# Using pjson library to get Yahoo stock quotes

Tags: j

I'm starting to learn J, so I have a basic question regarding a simple function reading a JSON with pjson library (J 8.0.7 beta, Windows 10):

```
load 'web/gethttp'
load 'convert/pjson'

stock=: 3 : 0
jsonstr =: gethttp 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=',y
dp =: dec_pjson_ jsonstr
)
```

I didn't get how to search for and get a value from the decoded JSON or unbox the result in 'dp', using the basic verbs (> or &.> to recursively reach the value I want). How can I do that?

I made it through with the 'raw' JSON string, but in a (I suspect) dumb way (modulo error checking):

```
load 'web/gethttp'

stock=: 3 : 0
jsonstr =: gethttp 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=',y
sdp=: ;: jsonstr                                NB. boxes the raw JSON string in word cells
matchstr=:('regularMarketPrice' & e.) &.> sdp   NB. find string on each cell - return cells with 1's for each matching char
summatch=:+/ &.> matchstr                       NB. sum the 1's in each cell
vec=: > summatch                                NB. unbox to a vector
index =: (i. >./) vec                           NB. find the index of the biggest number - is our searched string
tit=: index } sdp                               NB. Use index to get the title
val =: (index+2) } sdp                          NB. Use index to get the value
tit,val
)
stock 'PETR4.SA'
```

In case of not being possible to use the pjson, is there a better way to express the raw string version?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would approach it this way (comments follow `NB.` in code):

```
stock_base_=: 4 : 0             NB. I would make it dyadic so that I could specify the line I wanted displayed
jsonstr =. gethttp 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=',y   
qname=. <x                      NB. Box the x argument to allow imput to search for the line required
dp =. dec_pjson_  jsonstr       NB. Same approach as you
dp =.{. >> {: {.}:{. > }. {. dp NB. Strip off information that I don't need to create a two column table
qname ((= {."1) #  ] )dp        NB. Search the first column of the table for my x argument and return that line as a result
)
   'exchange' stock 'PETR4.SA'
┌────────┬───┐
│exchange│SAO│
└────────┴───┘
   'symbol' stock 'PETR4.SA'
┌──────┬────────┐
│symbol│PETR4.SA│
└──────┴────────┘
   'regularMarketDayHigh' stock 'PETR4.SA'
┌────────────────────┬─────┐
│regularMarketDayHigh│19.81│
└────────────────────┴─────┘
```

The line `dp =.{. >> {: {.}:{. > }. {. dp` is the one that bugs me the most, as there is probably a better way to clean up the table that `dec_pjson_` has produced, but this works.

Comment: I would prefer `fetch`: `((0 1);(0 1);0) {:: dp`

Comment: @bob thanks so much for your answer! A dyadic is indeed more flexible. The strip off and qname lines have new information to me, going to study it carefully.

Comment: @Eelvex your suggestion is clearer to me (I should have known this verb...), thanks!

Comment: I agree rand, the use of fetch by @eelvex is the approach that cleans up the line that I felt was deficient. I also looked at starting from scratch parsing the original jsonstrg, but it was easier to let dec_pjson_ do the work and then clean up the result. Someone else may use (;.)  Cut and (;:) Words to clean up jsongstr, but although it could work, it seemed messier than I wanted.